# inconvenient reading on small resolution displays

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Usually I read SO after work sitting on my sofa with my netbook. Its screen resolution is 1024x600, not very small actually. And I must say it's inconvenient to read SO because of lots of scrolling is required.

That's just a half of problem. With some practice you scroll fine by touchpad. But it doesn't help reading code blocks because they often have internal scrolling.

Was there requests to make SO adaptive to different resolutions? I can imagine why they would be rejected, sometimes such adaptiveness is pretty complicated. So I'm interested what people think about making code blocks not scrollable (e.g. wrapping lines with prefix like `>`). IMHO this should be simple enough to implement and can make reading more comfortable.

Comment: Thanks to @Pekka, I found [this userscript][1] that almost resolved my problem


  [1]: http://stackapps.com/questions/2574/click-to-expand-code-regions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So I'm interested what people think about making code blocks not scrollable (e.g. wrapping lines with prefix like >). IMHO this should be simple enough to implement and can make reading more comfortable.

Code blocks have scroll bars on purpose - it's a design choice and usually makes life easier for people reading questions.

I don't think this is really resolution dependent - it doesn't seem to make sense to turn them off for small resolutions, as the real issue here is the lack of a mouse.

I'm fairly sure there is a simple userscript to turn scrollbars off to help the situation... Anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: BTW, once I've seen mentioning of a userscript, but I don't know where to look for them and how to use, can you provide any useful link?

Comment: @Andy I can't - I'm not much into the userscript "scene" here on Meta :) but I'm sure somebody else can. There seems to be a strong `userscripts` tag, maybe there are answers there

Comment: Agreed, it's related with lack of a mouse, but only partially. Even having a mouse it would be more convenient to read w/o excessive scrolling. Since it's difficult to satisfy everybody's needs I'm going to look for suitable userscript